# How can I share a logger across a large application?

Tags: python, logging

I have an application that consists of many distinct modules, yet everything is still part of a single application. How can I properly share a logger, so that everything writes to the same file. Do I need to pass a logger around? I'd prefer not to have to do this.

Example project layout:

```
/
    __init__.py
    main_application.py
    functions_group1.py
    functions_group2.py
    functions_group3.py
```

I want to be able to define a [logger](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html) in `main_application.py` like so:

```
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
file_log = logging.FileHandler('logs/%s.log' % (file_name), 'a', encoding='UTF-8')
file_log.setLevel(file_level)
formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)-8s - %(name)-12s - %(message)s')
file_log.setFormatter(formatter)
logger.addHandler(file_log)
```

Then be able to use `logger` in `functions_group1`, `functions_group1`, `functions_group3` which are imported like this in `main_application`:

```
import functions_group1
import functions_group2
import functions_group3
```

Each of these files has only a list of functions (grouped by similar functionality)

*functions_group1*

```
def function1_dothing():
    # Want to log in here!
    return ...

def function1_dothing2():
    # Want to log in here!
    return ...

def function1_dothing3():
    # Want to log in here!
    return ...
```

How can I share the `logger` across the entire application?

Comment: Have you considered reading https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging.html?

Comment: What part do you recommend @jonrsharpe? I know how to create a logger. I don't know how to share it across the entire application without passing the logger object everywhere.

Comment: You don't need to *"share a single logger"*; each part builds a logger for its `__name__`, but you can configure what happens to those logs (e.g. writing to a file) at the top level of your module.

Comment: Ok. What if each of my functions_groups is just a list of functions then? It's not a true module with it's own __init__.py

Comment: I'm not sure what difference you think there is. Have you actually *tried* configuring a log file and seeing what happens with a call to `getLogger` everywhere you need to log?

Answer (score 3):

I think the point that you are missing is that by default, Python loggers are hierarchical. In your main application you simply create a logger with a fixed name (you can use the name of the main script). For example:

```
mainapp.py:

import logging

root_logger = logging.getLogger(appname())
# do any logger setup
```

where `appname()` is defined as:

```
def appname():
    return os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(sys.argv[0]))[0]
```

In any of your modules you can either get the root logger or get a child of the root logger.

```
moduleX.py:

import logging
module_logger = logging.getLogger("%s.moduleX" % (appname()))
```

Any logging that `module_logger` performs will be handled by the root logger. There's much more you can accomplish with the `logging` module. Maybe another read of https://docs.python.org/2/howto/logging.html with a different perspective will be valuable.